# help with equation simplification, can it be simplified further?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify the expression: 
$$\tag{1} \frac{\mu v}{k}r_2 \ln\left(\frac{r_2}{r_1}\right)+\beta \rho v^2 r_2^2 \left(\frac{1}{r_2}-\frac{1}{r_1}\right)+\frac{2\mu v}{k}r_2^2 \left(\frac{1}{r_2}-\frac{1}{r_1}\right)+\beta \rho v^2 r_2^4 \left(\frac{1}{3r_2^2}-\frac{1}{3r_1^2}\right)$$

after substituting the relationship given here for the variable $v$: 
$$\tag{2} v=\frac{N\mu}{\rho \beta k}$$

So far I have been able to simplify to: 
$$\tag{3} \frac{N \mu^2 }{\rho \beta k^2 }r_2 \left(\ln \left(\frac{r_2}{r_1}\right)+(N+2)\left[r_2 \left(\frac{1}{r_2}-\frac{1}{r_1}\right)\right]+Nr_2^3 \left(\frac{1}{3r_2^2}-\frac{1}{3r_1^2}\right)\right)$$

Can I simplify further?

Comment: Beyond the evident simplification $r_2/r_2=1$, based on a long practice, I see no hope. But why would you like to simplify it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie i.e.?, $$(N+2)(1-\frac{r_2}{r_1})+\frac{Nr_2}{3}(1-\frac{r_2^2}{r_1^2})$$ I am looking to simplify to make the calculation easier and thus less chance of calculation mistake when inputting values for these variables.

Comment: In that case calculate parts of it separately (e.g the middle square bracket, the last round bracket etc), write them down, then combine those numbers in a simple calculation. Don't try and do it in one go.